# Target probabilities in Platt's scaling with sigmoid regression

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, calibration

For model calibration, [Platt](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.41.1639&rep=rep1&type=pdf) suggested to use these target labels instead of $[0, 1]$:
$$
y_+=\frac{N_++1}{N_++2};\quad\quad y_-=\frac{1}{N_-+2}
$$
These new values to not sum up to $1$, so would cross-entropy still applicable for fitting this model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y_+$ and $y_-$ are not meant to sum to 1, and cross-entropy is applicable.

The first is the probability you try to fit for a positive true class; the corresponding negative-class probability is 1/(N+ + 2). Those sum to 1.

Similarly, if the true class is negative, you use $y_-$. This and its complement (for a positive predicted class) sum to 1.

These are meant to be posterior probabilities, e.g. $p(\text{predict-positive} \mid \text{actually-positive})$.